# How to change Header section on scrolling in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to change header section while scrolling horizontal sidebar in angular.
By using the hostlister I have implemented this but it's not working as intended.

**code in example.ts file**

```
import {Component,HostListener} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Implicit main content with two sidenavs */
@Component({
  selector: 'sidenav-position-example',
  templateUrl: 'sidenav-position-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['sidenav-position-example.css'],
})
@HostListener('window:scroll', [])
export class SidenavPositionExample {
scrolled : boolean =  true;
onWindowScroll() {
    this.scrolled = window.pageYOffset >48;
    }
}
```

**html code**

```
<div style="min-height: 150vh;"> <!-- Set minimum height to force a scrollbar -->
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        <mat-toolbar-row>
            <span>Header 1</span>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <mat-toolbar color="secondary" style="position: fixed; top: 0;" *ngIf="scrolled">
        <mat-toolbar-row>
            <span>Header 2</span>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

[A Stackblitz of what I tried](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pj5rjj?file=app%2Fsidenav-position-example.ts)

[A demo of what I want](https://xrv5pw.axshare.com/#id=yrdg9w&p=home&c=1)

Comment: Please post code inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution only displays header-2 when the user scrolls down further than a given value but won't show header-1 again as soon as the user scrolls up, like on the demo page you posted. Header-1 only appears again if the user scrolls back to the top.

To slide header-1 back in as soon as the user scrolls up you have to determine the current scroll direction whenever a scroll event is fired. To do so you can create an observable stream of scroll positions, map them to UP / DOWN directions and set a header state accordingly. Then use animations to slide the headers in and out depending on the observed header state.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pj5rjj-8asowc

```ts
import { Component, HostListener, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged, map, pairwise, takeUntil, throttleTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

export enum VisibilityState { Visible = 'visible', Hidden = 'hidden' }  
export enum Direction { None = 'None', Up = 'Up', Down = 'Down' }

@Component({
  selector: 'sidenav-position-example',
  templateUrl: 'sidenav-position-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['sidenav-position-example.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('scrollAnimation', [
      state(VisibilityState.Visible, style({ transform: 'translateY(0)' })),
      state(VisibilityState.Hidden, style({ transform: 'translateY(-64px)' })), // adjust this to the height of your header
      transition(`${VisibilityState.Visible} => ${VisibilityState.Hidden}`, animate('250ms')),
      transition(`${VisibilityState.Hidden} => ${VisibilityState.Visible}`, animate('250ms'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class SidenavPositionExample implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  private destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  isHeader1Visible = VisibilityState.Visible;
  isHeader2Visible = VisibilityState.Hidden;
  slideHeader2InAtPosition = 30;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // create an observable stream of scroll positions and map them to UP / DOWN directions
    const content = document.querySelector('.scrollWrapper');
    // if the scroll events happen on your window you could use 'window' instead of 
    // 'content' here
    const scroll$ = fromEvent(content, 'scroll').pipe(
      throttleTime(10),
      // if you used 'window' above replace 'content.scrollTop' with 'window.pageYOffset'
      map(() => content.scrollTop),
      pairwise(),
      map(([y1, y2]): Direction => (y2 < y1 ? Direction.Up : (y2 > this.slideHeader2InAtPosition ? Direction.Down : Direction.None))),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    );

    // subscribe to the UP / DOWN scroll direction stream and set the header state accordingly
    scroll$.subscribe(dir => {
      if (dir === Direction.Down) { // scrolling down
        this.isHeader1Visible = VisibilityState.Hidden;
        this.isHeader2Visible = VisibilityState.Visible;
      } else { // scrolling up
        this.isHeader1Visible = VisibilityState.Visible;
        this.isHeader2Visible = VisibilityState.Hidden;
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

I changed the HTML a little but you could also use a different setup and then set the element that gets scrolled accordingly in the code above or simply listen to scroll events on the `window`.

```html
<div class="headerWrapper">
  <mat-toolbar class="header" color="primary" [@scrollAnimation]="isHeader1Visible">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <span>Header 1</span>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-toolbar class="header" color="secondary" [@scrollAnimation]="isHeader2Visible">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <span>Header 2</span>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
</div>
<div class="scrollWrapper">
  <div class="scrollContent">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pj5rjj-6mz2vh?file=app%2Fsidenav-position-example.ts   for  the above one if we need to keep the same header effect for parent scroll  how can we  achive.instead of creating the content

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Which element's scroll events do you want to observe?

Comment: for the  parent  header when we scroll headerto be changed  here is the link 
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pj5rjj-wwhv1t?embed=1&file=app/sidenav-position-example.html

Comment: @poojariraj what to do mean by 'parent header'? The stackblitz you posted works as expected. Please post a stackblitz with the exact html setup of your app, so I can help you. As I wrote in my answer you can always listen to the scroll events on the `window` if that's what you need.

Comment: @friddo Here i am sharing the  stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pj5rjj-zk73b1?embed=1&file=app/sidenav-position-example.css      in  this  example we have two scroll bars when we scroll parent scroll and child scroll i need any  one scroll bar to be displayed and wen we scroll header to be change it should scroll up to last content.thanks in advance

Comment: @poojariraj The stackblitz you posted still doesn't make it clear what you want! Where is your side-nav-content? It's empty! Please remove my code and only keep your own code, make the html sections that should be scrollable scrollable and label them clearly. E.g. You labeled a table in your code scrollable, but it's not scrollable. Make it scrollable! Also indent your code correctly. Your could also add screenshots of your app to your question and mark the scrollable sections there!

Comment: https://r7mv94.axshare.com/#id=789eoa&p=widgetsection&view=d&c=1  this is the ux screen refece like this i need to implement

Comment: Have you tried listening to the `window.pageYOffset` value, as I wrote in my answer? Is this what you're looking for: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pj5rjj-sgtibu

Comment: Yes fridoo Thank you so much.. How can i connect with u. is there linked in

Comment: @poojariraj I'm not on linkedin, but you could upvote my answer if I helped you. If you're having further problems you can ask another question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @firdoo how to reduce the height of the row https://stackblitz.com/angular/dnbermjydavk?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.ts. here is the link thnaks in advance i tried but its not reducing

Comment: Hi @poojariraj that is a separate question unrelated to changing the header when scrolling. Please ask a new question on stackoverflow. Please also consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) an answer that has solved your problem by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3):

**HostListener** should not be placed on the component class it should be inside the class methods

This part is wrong

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', [])
export class SidenavPositionExample {
```

Your component class should be like this

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

/** @title Implicit main content with two sidenavs */
@Component({
  selector: 'sidenav-position-example',
  templateUrl: 'sidenav-position-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['sidenav-position-example.css'],
})
export class SidenavPositionExample {
  scrolled: boolean = false;

  // for initialization
  constructor() {
    this.scrolled = window.pageYOffset > 48;
  }


  @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    this.scrolled = window.pageYOffset > 48;
  }
}
```

Comment: A bit off topic I guess, but is it platform agnostic (a best practice) to use window like that in your code? Is there any other way to avoid it maybe? Thanks.

Comment: @DawidZbiński you could listen to `Element.scrollTop` instead, if the scrolling happens within a certain element.

Comment: @fridoo Iam having small query  when we fetching the data on clicking the button load to be loaded and utill the data comes web page to be disabled for that code is there ill share you please help me out Stack:blitz Link: After clicking the button overlay-loader css class to be loaded and once data get fetched css overlay-loader to be dissaper       stack overflow link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54439571/calling-the-css-style-from-typescript-append-it-to-html-file